# Script not found error after running yarn tsc in Docker

Tags: typescript, docker, yarnpkg

I built my project with docker running `yarn tsc`. When I ran `docker run -p88:5011 accounts2`

I get error `PM2 error: Error: Script not found: /home/accounts/dist/server/index.js` which of course if I follow the process manually shows up.

here is my docker file

```
FROM node:10.16-alpine
# Install PM2
RUN npm install pm2 -g
# Add bash support to image
RUN apk add --no-cache bash
# Create service directory
RUN mkdir -p /home/accounts

WORKDIR /home/accounts
# Copy working files
COPY package.json /home/accounts
COPY . /home/accounts
# Install dependencies
RUN yarn install
RUN yarn tsc
EXPOSE 5011
# Start command
CMD [ "pm2-runtime", "process.yml" ]
```

my process.yml

```
apps:

  - script: ./dist/server/index.js
    name: accounts
    instances: maad
    exec_mode: cluster
    watch: false
    autorestart: true
    out_file: /dev/null
    ignore_watch:
        - logs
        - node_modules
        - worker\.js
        - \.git/index\.lock
        - \.log
        - \.lock
    watch_options:
        followSymlinks: false
```

DIR Structure

```
home/
 .circleci/
  config.yml
 src/
 dist/
  server/
   index.js
 process.yml
```

Comment: are you sure that `COPY package.json /home/accounts` should not point to `/home/accounts-service`? Same for the line after that

Comment: @ClemensKaserer I have updated the error

Comment: Okay, then your WORKDIR definition is not correct. Shouldn't WORKDIR be `WORKDIR /home/accounts` and not `WORKDIR /home/accounts-service`? Since your error states: `/home/accounts/dist/server/index.js` not found and your index.js is in `/home/accounts-service/dist/server/index.js`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are copying application to  `/home/accounts`, where its not the working directory, it should be

```
WORKDIR /home/accounts-service
COPY . .
```

or  you set the WORKDIR to

```
WORKDIR /home/accounts
```

As when container start `pm2-runtime` looking at the current working directory, as you are using a relative path in `process.yml`.

```
script  (string)    ”./api/app.js”  script path relative to pm2 start
```

[pm2-application-declaration](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/application-declaration/)

Comment: I have changed the working directory and modified the question but same thing

Comment: did you add `WORKDIR /home/accounts-service
COPY . .` and can you show structure of your code?

Comment: I simply changed to `WORKDIR /home/accounts`

Comment: added structure @Adiii

Comment: I am not seeing `process.yml`

Comment: I have included it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203040/discussion-between-adiii-and-king).

Answer (score 0):

If your docker-compose has a volume configuration you need to ensure that you have run the production build locally. The instance is looking for the app.js or server.js script at the local root folder, not at the docker container folder.

```
volumes:
        - ./app:/home/accounts
```

If you want the docker instance to fetch the file from within, then you can remove the volume from the docker compose configuration.